# Detect old file name and new file name via FSEventsFramework

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation, fsevents

I am using `FSEventsFramework` to monitor directories for changes. I was wondering if my logic here is sound, for detecting old file name and new name after a rename.

- I think on rename, both events are in the same callback.
- Old file name will have event id X-1
- New file name will have even id X

Is this true?

Thanks

Comment: Your logic works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I experienced it, your assumption is not always true. On FSEventStreamCreate you will pass a latency as well as a flag for the meaning of the latency `kFSEventStreamCreateFlagNoDefer`. Therefore the events may or may not come in the same callback. Furthermore there are different ways the file can be renamed. Some Filesystem-APIs actually rename the file while keeping the inode like `mv`, others like NSDocument create a new inode. Sometimes you will receive kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed in the callback, sometimes not.

EDIT: Alternatives to FSEvents are [Kernel Queues](http://on/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html) and [`NSFileCoordinator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010585-CH1-SW2)

FSEvents are somehow not fully documented in the API-Docs. Have a look at the header file FSEvent.h, there is more to read there.

Then to easily see what is going on for a rename, run your app and do some renaming with Finder, with terminal mv as well as in a document based app using the small triangle right to the filename.

Comment: Thanks mahal, I set the latency to 0 do you think in that case the should come in same callback? But regardless if in same CB do you know if the old/new rename event should be X and X+1 event id?

Comment: Thanks @mahal for your edits! :) Do you mean for kernel queues this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html

Comment: @Noitidart  did this answer help you? if yes, would you like to accept it using the green checkmark left hand to my answer?